# Technical reason for no OUTPUT clause when triggers present?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers, output

It is well-documented that you cannot use an `OUTPUT` clause with DML statements on a table that has triggers. Workarounds are fairly easy to find. You can, for instance, use `OUTPUT INTO` with a table variable. But what I haven't been able to find is any kind of technical explanation of *why* this is the case. Does anybody know? How is `OUTPUT` with an `INTO` clause so fundamentally different from `OUTPUT` without an `INTO` clause, and why is it the presence of triggers that makes a difference??

Comment: I don't know that you're going to get a satisfactory answer out on the public domain from someone who didn't work on the code or at least the implementation of the error message. But I suspect there is some conflict with both the trigger and the `OUTPUT` clause needing `inserted`/`deleted`.

Comment: Well, my _speculation_ is that there is a data structure representing the execution of a database object, and that data structure has a field that points at an output stream. When your table has triggers, this field is initialized for use by the triggers to write output. When you use an `OUTPUT` clause, the field is used by the DML statement itself for output. If you try to do both at the same time, then one will overwrite the other, because they're initialized in different places/code paths. `OUTPUT INTO`, though, has a different field identifying a table instead of a stream. That's my guess.

Comment: I was hoping to have more than a well-educated guess, though :-P

Comment: Hmm, but, if you have a trigger on the table, that trigger can actually supply _output_ from a DML statement, even if the actual effect of the DML is unaltered. I think that's where the conflict lies.`CREATE TABLE TestTable (Value INT NOT NULL); GO; CREATE TRIGGER TestTable_TestTrigger ON TestTable FOR INSERT AS SELECT 42;` -- now when you `INSERT INTO TestTable VALUE(1)`, you get a table in the result with value `42` in it. That table probably is sitting in the same part of the execution data structure as would be used for an `OUTPUT` clause on the `INSERT INTO`. That is my speculation.

Comment: It's either that, or it's about correctness, because the trigger can actually alter the data you have inserted, so it might persist different values than what the DML statement originally emitted in its `OUTPUT` clause. _Buttt_, if it were about correctness, then why would `OUTPUT INTO` be permitted? That'll have the same problem, where the trigger could subsequently change the value.

Comment: Ah I thought you were asking about the error `The target table 'T' of the DML statement cannot have any enabled triggers if the statement contains an OUTPUT clause without INTO clause.` but see you are asking about `The target table 'T' of the OUTPUT INTO clause cannot have any enabled triggers.`

Comment: That's related, though, and I hadn't even thought of that. Your answer _was_ useful and added important nuance. But, yes, it technically was answering the wrong question :-P

Comment: But `SELECT 42` doesn't need to involve `inserted/deleted`.